# Is it logical to register non static method as callback function?

Tags: c++, callback, static

I created 2 class.class `KeyLogger` and class `cHookProc`

first i create `cHookProc` in `KeyLogger` class.

then i get address of `LRESULT CALLBACK cHookProc::HookProc` by `unsigned int cHookProc::getCallBackAddr()`

is it logical and works fine always?

this is `KeyLogger.h`

```
#pragma once
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>

class cHookProc{
public:
    LRESULT CALLBACK HookProc(int code, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp);
    unsigned int getCallBackAddr();
private:
};

class KeyLogger{
public:
    KeyLogger();
    ~KeyLogger();
private:
    cHookProc *cHkProc;
};
```

and this is `KeyLogger.cpp`

```
#include "KeyLogger.h"

KeyLogger::KeyLogger(){
    cHkProc = new cHookProc;
    int i = cHkProc->getCallBackAddr();
    HOOKPROC hprc = (HOOKPROC)i;
    HHOOK keyHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, hprc, NULL, NULL);
}
KeyLogger::~KeyLogger(){
    delete cHkProc;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK cHookProc::HookProc(int code, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp){
    if (code == 0){
    .
    .
    .
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, wp, lp);
}
unsigned int cHookProc::getCallBackAddr(){
    LRESULT(__stdcall cHookProc::*ptrtofn)(int, WPARAM, LPARAM) = &cHookProc::HookProc;
    unsigned int *i;
    i = (unsigned int*)&ptrtofn;
    return *i;
}
```

Comment: You can't, really, since non-static member functions needs an object to be called on. If you don't have that then you could make a static member function wrapper, ***if*** that function could also access an instance (object) of the class.

Comment: Putting address into `int` is not going to work. Non-static member can not be registered as callback because signature mismatch.

Comment: @VTT after searching a lot i found out your answer is exactly correct and my code is not correct. thanks.

Comment: If the code that is using the callback has access to an instance of the class (or an instance of a derived class) it can make sense to register a member function of that class as a callback.  But that is only true if the code using the callback will associate the member function with the class instance and call it correctly.   That is a very narrow set of conditions where it is applicable.    Most callback schemes aim to be more general than that (e.g. useful in more contexts than a single class or its set of derived classes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function doesn't use any method from the class, then it might work, but it's just random chance, and it will break if you change the function and add references to the object. Make it a static method in that case.

A callback on a method should be wrapped with a reference to the object on which the method is called.

Also use a unique pointer for `cHkProc`.

Comment: I register non static method after creating class. doesn't it make my code safe?

Comment: If your callback is not called on a method, then it's wrong, plain wrong.